# n-way ANOVA test of signifance for multiple variable and groups in python

Tags: python, pandas, anova, hypothesis-test

I have a data frame with columns: "category", "count", and "phase". Sample data looks like:

| category | count | phase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| International Politics | 4221 | phase0 |
| Economy | 6182 | phase1 |
| Domestic affairs | 1151 | phase0 |
| Occupation | 1892 | phase0 |
| Combat | 1122 | phase0 |
| Domestic affairs | 4221 | phase2 |
| International Politics | 611 | phase2 |
| International Politics | 918 | phase3 |
| Economy | 4282 | phase3 |
| International Politics | 6212 | phase5 |
| Occupation | 5142 | phase4 |

Each phase (phase0, phase1, phase2, and so on) can have a different number of unique corresponding categories. For example, phase0 unique categories are: International Politics, Domestic affairs, Combat, and phase3 unique categories are: International Politics, economy. Count is the count of a category for a given phase.

My objective is to check whether the categories are statistically significant across the phases or not. I am trying to use the n-way ANOVA test for that. I followed the instructions provided by [this site](https://www.pythonfordatascience.org/factorial-anova-python/). However, I am still confused about how to implement it. How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: n-way anova is for testing means across different groups. You have count data. Are you sure you need 2 way anova here? Notice how you do not have repeats.  What exactly do you mean by categories being statistically significant across the phases?? Do you mean categories are dependent on the phases? - Test of independence, the mean of categories are same/different  controlling for phases - 2 way anova/RBD. I doubt the statement *categories are significant across the phases* makes any sense

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for the reply. Yes, I want to show that Categories are dependent on the phases. Let me provide some context. By saying categories are significant across the phases, I want to conclude that these categories do not occur across the phases randomly. They are related in some sense. It is quite important in my use case.

Comment: That is a chisq-test and not an anova test. I believe you are looking for chisq test

Comment: @Onyambu The Formula I used for ANOVA analysis is: 
count ~ C(category) + C(phase) + C(category):C(phase). Explanation of null hypothesis provided by chatgpt for the given formula and table is: Interaction Effect (C(category):C(phase)). H0: The effect of category on count is the same across all levels of phase, and vice versa. In other words, there is no interaction effect between category and phase. H1: The effect of category on count varies across different levels of phase, and vice versa. In other words, there is an interaction effect between category and phase.

is explanation right?